# how to base64 decode a file and get the mime type

Tags: php

I have base64encoded a file, now I do the following to decode it and save the file contents to a database

```
        $base_64_data = str_replace(' ', '+', $base_64_data);
        $data = explode(',', $base_64_data);
        // decode the data
        $data = base64_decode(end($data));

        // create a temp file with the data
        $tmp = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), 'file');
        $fh = fopen($tmp, 'wb');
        fwrite($fh, $data);
        fclose($fh);


        $size = filesize($tmp);
        $params = [
            'name' => $tmp,
            'size' => $size,
            'mimetype' => mime_content_type($tmp),
            'data' => $data,
        ];
```

How do I get the name of the file? and the mimetype? Is this the correct way to basedecode a baseencoded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check its [Magic Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files) to help you in striking out what file it isn't. Other than that there is no way to know its file type. Base 64-encoded string can contain literally any data.

Answer (score 0):

The base64 encoding of a file doesn't contain its filename. You need the client to send the filename alongside the base64 representation, using a separate property.

You can infer the mime-type of a binary file (after having it decoded from a base64 representation) using the `mime_content_type` function; you're code already does this.